# print ajax result in another page without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

The below shown is AJAX code where fetches data from database and prints the data inside the div with id display. in this case, my code is working perfectly

But my requirement is to print the data in another page without refreshing the SECOND PAGE

To make it clear please check the two images

**IMAGE1 :**

[image]

**IMAGE2 :**

[image]

I used this below Ajax query for my requirement

```
'$(document).ready(function(){
    displayFromDatabase();
displayaddress();   
    });
function displayFromDatabase(){

$.ajax({

    url:"query.php",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: {"display":'1'},
    success: function(data){
        $('#display').html(data);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is not possible. The only way I can imagine: if you open the second window by window.open() you can use the returned window-object to change the content. Or you have to use an ASYNCHRONIOUS function in your second page.

Comment: it"s working is just like Gmail if a user sends mail to us while we are online we can see it without refreshing the page

Comment: Yes, as far as I know with a message queue. If you want to do it like gmail, you need the observer pattern. Or you implement a javascript-function, which checks for new content on your second screen. But "onclick" will not work, expect with the returned object of window.open() function.

Comment: what else we can do other than on click function

Comment: no one here to help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Do as following :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        displayFromDatabase();
    displayaddress();   
        });
    function displayFromDatabase(){
    $.ajax({

    url:"query.php",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: {"display":'1'},
    success: function(data){
        //$('#display').html(data);
        var newWindow = window.open("", "new window", "width=200, height=100");
       //write the data to the document of the newWindow
       newWindow.document.write(data);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: THIS IS WORKING BUT THIS IS NOT MY REQUIREMENT.As above shown the one window with button is user and the second window is admin so both of them have connection in between and the admin needed to view the result without refresh

Answer (score 0):

**This Might Be Helpful**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    displayFromDatabase();
    displayaddress();   
});

function displayFromDatabase(){
    $.ajax({
         url:"query.php",
         type: "POST",
         async: false,
         data: {"display":'1'},
         success: function(data){
             //$('#display').html(data);
             var win=window.open('about:blank');
             with(win.document)
             {
                  open();
                  write(data);
                  close();
             }
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: THIS IS NOT MY REQUIREMENT.As above shown the one window with button is user and the second window is admin so both of them have connection in between and the admin needed to view the result without refresh